# 2 Navigation Bars on moreNavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

When I click moreNavigationController on TabBarController, there will be 2 navigation bars displaying on the screen. Does anyone have a clue?

Project Files Link -> https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9507586/FubonInsuranceTest.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do one thing In your tabbar.m class add this line of code.

```
 [morenavbar setHidden:YES];
```

In this function

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController 
  willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
                animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: The navigation bar of moreNavigationController will disappear, but when I click one of the tableview cell in moreNavigationController, there will no way to pop back to the previous tableview except I click moreNavigationController TabBarItem.

Comment: Then why r you not remove default nav bar and create your own custom nav bar?

Answer (score 1):

in `viewWillAppear` function of the moreNavigationController class,
add the following line of code

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```